# image src dataUrl некорректно работает jQuery.rotate.js

Tags: javascript, canvas

Всем привет!
вот [codePen](https://codepen.io/yurri_87/pen/KxZOJm).
Есть картинка, src dataUrl.
Для поворота (клик по body) используется плагин jQuery.rotate.js (зашит в codePen).
Первый поворот проходит нормально, последующие - некорректно.
Между поворотами у картинки берется `dataUrl` и присваивается `image.origin` (там собственно хранится картинка, так нужно), после чего происходит обновление `image.refresh()`.
Если не использовать промежуточное сохранение, то все работает корректно (создается canvas и вращается нормально).
В чем может быть проблема?
Суть задачи в том, чтобы после каждого поворота получать в image.origin.src новый blob. Потом перезагрузить картинку (в моем случае это image.refresh()), и потом, при необходимости снова повернуть в ту же сторону (возникает проблема поворота). Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы такая система работала. Повернуть используя класс CSS - не выход, ведь он не изменяет blob.
т.е. получение blob - не проблема. Проблема в том, что следующий поворот работает некорректно.

Comment: Вставьте норм url, а не base64 такой огромный

Comment: изначально так и было, но если делать на codePen, то при попытке кросдоменного получения base64 с помощью .toDataUrl браузер выдает ошибку, поэтому пришлось вставить картинку извращенным путем.

Answer (score 0):

Тут не столько JS сколько CSS надо, на Sass еще в разы короче будет темболее если будет [auto-prefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer).

```js
const
  url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg',
  container = document.querySelector('#container'),
  img = container.querySelector('img'),
  btn = document.querySelectorAll('.button')
    
setAngle(270) // ставит начальный угол
setBase64() // устанавливает src как base64 используя url

// каждой кнопке дает слушатель нажатия в котором изменяется угол исходя от значения data-angle атрибута
;[...btn].forEach(i =>
  i.onclick = () => setAngle(img.angle + +i.dataset.angle)
)

// ставит угол
function setAngle (angle) {
  const oldAngle = img.angle
  angle = angle % 360
  
  if (angle < 0)
    angle = 360 - angle
  if (angle === 450)
    angle = 270
    
  img.angle = angle 
  container.classList.remove('rotate' + oldAngle) // удаялет прошлый класс
  container.classList.add('rotate' + img.angle) // ставит класс исходя от угла
}

// получает из картинки base64 и ставит его
function setBase64 () {
  toDataURL(url)
  .then(base64 => {
    img.src = base64
  })
}

// получает из картинки base64
function toDataURL (url) { 
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.blob()) // переводит в blob
    .then(blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader() // blob умеет читать FileReader
      reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result) // когда считало
      reader.onerror = reject // если вдруг ошибка
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob) // читает как base64
    }))
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  /* IE 10+, Firefox, и т.п. */
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  /* Chrome */
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  /* IE 9 */
}



#container.rotate90 img {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
}
#container.rotate180 img {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-100%, -100%);
}
#container.rotate270 img {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 250px; text-align: center;">
  <button class="button" data-angle="+90">◄ Повернуть </button>
  <button class="button" data-angle="-90">Повернуть ►</button>
  <div id="container">
    <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне необходимо получить base64, присвоить их image.origin.src, потом обновить картинку с помощью image.refresh(), а потом еще раз корректно повернуть фигуру.

Comment: Переделал свой код под base64

Comment: Суть задачи в том, чтобы после каждого поворота получать в image.origin.src новый blob. Потом перезагрузить картинку (в моем случае это image.refresh()), и потом, при необходимости снова повернуть в ту же сторону (возникает проблема поворота). Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы такая система работала. Повернуть используя класс CSS - не выход, ведь он не изменяет blob.

Comment: т.е. получение blob - не проблема. Проблема в том, что следующий поворот работает некорректно.